# css of application.html.erb is not loading for a particular controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller

I have 3 controllers.

`users_controller.rb`, `user_posts_controller.rb` , `sessions_controller.rb`. and their views.

The problem is, for the first two controller `application.html.erb` is loading correctly with corresponding css, but for the last controller some how the `application.html.erb` misses its css properties. I am not able to understand why is this. What could be the problem here?

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/user_posts/assets/css/icons/icomoon/styles.css"):
  actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
```

Why does this error come for only user_posts? All my controllers are almost the same.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue. The problem was because the route for the user_posts#index was not generated correctly. When I fixed this it started working correctly.